# Dynamic translate3d by adding a number per click

Tags: javascript, jquery, translate3d

Hi so I'm trying to simulate arrows in a slider, where I move the elements to the left and right.

So far I have the items moving to the right but only once.

https://i.gyazo.com/34a0ef4a5064c2942aca7c717a775e8b.mp4

Here is my code so far

```
<script>
  (function(){
    const arrowLeft = document.querySelector('#video-tags-left');
    const arrowRight = document.querySelector('#video-tags-right');
    const tags = document.querySelector('.video-tags');
    const now = "740";

    arrowRight.addEventListener("click", function() {
      $(tags).css({
        "transform": "translate3d(" + -now + "px, 0px, 0px)",
        "transform-style": "preserve-3d"
       });
    });

    arrowLeft.addEventListener("click", function() {
      $(tags).css({
        "transform": "translate3d("+ +now+", 0px, 0px)",
        "transform-style": "preserve-3d"
       });
    });
}());
</script>
```

So I'm trying to add and remove `now` which is 740 on click, so add 740 every time I click right and remove when I click left until it resets to 0px.

So I click right once 740 again 1460 etc and the reverse when the user clicks the left arrow.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some problems with your code:

1. You declared "now" as const, therefore it's value cannot be changed
2. You declared "now" as type string, therefore you cannot do any mathematical operations with it (such as incrementing or decrementing)

Change your code to this:

```
<script>
  (function(){
    const arrowLeft = document.querySelector('#video-tags-left');
    const arrowRight = document.querySelector('#video-tags-right');
    const tags = document.querySelector('.video-tags');
    let now = 740; // Declare "now" as variable of type number

    arrowRight.addEventListener("click", function() {
      now += 740; // Increment "now" by 740
      $(tags).css({
        "transform": "translate3d(" + now + "px, 0px, 0px)",
        "transform-style": "preserve-3d"
       });
    });

    arrowLeft.addEventListener("click", function() {
      now -= 740; // Decrement "now" by 740
      $(tags).css({
        "transform": "translate3d(" + now + "px, 0px, 0px)",
        "transform-style": "preserve-3d"
       });
    });
}());
</script>
```

Comment: Oh, ok thanks for pointing out the issues and what I'm doing wrong, it's a great help. This works I have to click twice for the code to kick in but when I go to click the left arrow to go back the position resets back to 0 https://i.gyazo.com/a6b25485f2d1eab33419a297abf78790.mp4 ideally it should go back 740 not reset

Comment: @B.J.B Are you sure you implemented my code correctly? Because it works when I try it. Here's a working Codepen - https://codepen.io/merkur0/pen/gyJXoX

Comment: What I mean by this is that the value starts at 740 clicking the right arrow the value in the console and translate goes up, however, when clicking to go back down again the console number changes but the value in translate doesn't https://gyazo.com/2e866187ba3803cb70226c714994f989

Comment: I just noticed that there was a typo in your code (and therefore in the code I posted too).
This:
`"transform": "translate3d(" + now + ", 0px, 0px)",`
Should be:
`"transform": "translate3d(" + now + "px, 0px, 0px)",`

I updated my code.

Comment: Oh haha, that's my bad. One more thing, is it possible to limit the state to 0 so I can't go back further and therefore into minus?

Comment: Of course it is, but we can't do everything for you. Try figuring that out yourself and make another post if you run into issues. _Hint: You want to only execute the code that decrements the variable if the value is higher than zero._ Good luck.

Comment: I've tried https://gyazo.com/8c7513e804e8b69e7836677451baae08 however it doesn't decrement now. I can't go back.

Answer (score 0):

Every time you click on one of the arrows you should increment/decrement the value of `now`:

```
<script>
    (function(){
        const arrowLeft = document.querySelector('#video-tags-left');
        const arrowRight = document.querySelector('#video-tags-right');
        const tags = document.querySelector('.video-tags');
        const SLIDER_WIDTH = 740;
        let now = 0;

        arrowRight.addEventListener("click", function() {
            now -= SLIDER_WIDTH;
            $(tags).css({
                "transform": "translate3d(" + now + "px, 0px, 0px)",
                "transform-style": "preserve-3d"
            });
        });

        arrowLeft.addEventListener("click", function() {
            now += SLIDER_WIDTH;
            $(tags).css({
                "transform": "translate3d("+ now + "px, 0px, 0px)",
                "transform-style": "preserve-3d"
            });
        });
    }());
</script>
```

Take into account that you will also have to check the limits of your slider so that you can not move the slider to sections where there is no content.

Comment: How would I go about checking the limits?

Comment: Well, the left limit seems to be the initial position (when `now` is equal to 0). The right limit will depend on the number of total items you have and the items you show in a slide.